# What is the probability that for exactly three calls the lines are occupied?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I am unable to understand the following statement.

The phone lines to an airline reservation system are occupied 40% of the time. Assume that the events that the lines are occupied on successive calls are independent. Assume that 10 calls are placed to the airline.

$\textbf{What is the probability that for exactly three calls the lines are occupied?}$

I am not exactly confused with how I will find the answer. I am simply having difficulties understanding the question.

Here is my current understanding of the statement:

Each of the phone lines of an airline reservation system are occupied 40% of the time on a certain time interval. The probability that one phone line is occupied is independent of the vacancy of other phone lines, thus, the probability that any phone lines will be occupied at a given time interval will always be 40%. $\textbf{The airline has 10 phone lines.}$

The last sentence stating "Assume that 10 calls are placed to the airline" confuses me. Does this mean that the airline has 10 phone lines? Or are there 10 phone calls to the airline. The latter interpretation seems to be pointless however. I just want to make sure that I am not missing something.

Comment: The airline has a switchboard which, at any given time, has probability $0.4$ of saying we are busy, go away. Ten calls are made to the airline. What is the probability that exactly $3$ of the people will be told to go away?

Comment: I think my question is, if that is the case, how many phone lines does the airline have? Or if we assume it only has one phone line, then the question is, under what time frame that I have to find the probability that exactly 3 of the people will be told to go away. 3 people will be told to go away in a day? And how long does each call have to be?

Comment: There could be any number of phone lines. No time frame implied. The problem asks us to assume, implausibly, that the events "Busy for this call" and "busy for the next call" are independent. This assumption makes lengths of phone calls irrelevant. You are made uncomfortable by this because you know that lengths of phone calls *are* relevant, and time  frame is relevant. But the author makes the explicit assumption of independence, partly because otherwise the problem cannot be solved without much more information.

Comment: I think I know the problem here. 10 calls are made. What is the probability that 3 out of those 10 calls make the phone line busy. My problem is that I assumed that any one call will make the phone line busy. Since I fail to see the logic in taking a call while having the phone line you use to take the call remains unoccupied and vacant.

Comment: Yes, that is what is intended, exactly three busy signals in $10$ calls, assuming independence. Not a very good problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that there is one thing called "The phone lines to an airline reservation system" and they as a whole are occupied for 40% of time.

For each call this thing can be either occupied (40%) or not and for each call this event is independent.

We take 10 calls.

What is the probability that for exactly three calls the lines (thing) are occupied?

Should be simple application of binomial law.

Comment: Hmm, I assume that for each call taken the line will be occupied. I believe your interpretation is correct, but I fail to see how taking a call from an external party can leave the phone system unoccupied, since there is only one phone line.

Comment: Well, just trying to think some sense into this problem.
Say we have huge and very busy reservation system with many lines and many calls. Maybe 1000 lines, every call is short. With 40% probability, all lines are occupied, with 60% probability there is at least 1 free line.
Then those 10 calls, which are made for testing purposes. Someone wants to check quality of service, for instance. Those calls are made.. say, once in minute. Then we can really say that all test-calls are independent of each other.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you're interpretation of the situation is correct.

Let $X$ be the discrete random variable 'no. of lines occupied'

Then $X \sim \mathrm{Bin}(x;0.4,10)$

$$P(X=3)=\cfrac{10!}{(10-3)!\cdot3!}\times 0.4^3\times0.6^7$$

Comment: I do understand the application of a binomial distribution, I just need a confirmation that my interpretation is correct. Why say 10 calls instead of 10 phone lines? Seems inaccurate.

Comment: @amundi32 Perhaps "10 calls placed to the airline" is simply an abstract way of saying the plane has 10 phone lines _placed_ on it

Comment: I am leaning towards that idea. But this is a past exam question, so I just find it quite unlikely that they use such an abstract wording for this, given the likeliness for misinterpretation.

Comment: @amundi32 Do you mind if I ask what examination level this is? Is it A-Level equivalent or something higher? Also, you have no doubt typed it out word for word anyway but do you have a source? Assuming that your institution allows distribution of such information. I ask these question because if I can find out the examination level it will give me a clue as to what the question is really asking - whether it be the above case or something more complicated.

Comment: It is actually a university examination for a stats question. It's for STA256 (Probability and Statistics I). I doubt sending you the paper would help since there is no centralized institution that standardizes the exam. I guess the professors themselves wrote the exam.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question is actually pointing to a timeframe - 3 consecutive (or concurrent) calls and the probability that each of the phones is busy for either 3 calls in a row or 3 incoming callers

Comment: I don't believe it has to be consecutive. I do agree with your logic. It's just that I failed to see how can taking a call from an incoming caller can make the phone not busy. So I initially assumed taking 10 calls would mean that the phone would be busy for each of the 10 calls taken